# Spring @Value escape colon(:) in default value

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, spring-properties

I have the following property annotated with @Value.  I have a default value defined using the default separator of ':"

```
@Value("${prop.url:http://myurl.com}")
```

Is there a way to escape the ':' in `http://myurl.com` or do I have to define a different separator value in my configuration.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**Update:**
For spring 4.2 and higher, no single quotes are needed. Spring will see the first colon as special, and use all the rest as a single string value.

For spring 4.2 and higher,

```
@Value("${prop.url:http://myurl.com}")
```

For the previous versions, I believe single quotes will do the trick:

```
@Value("${prop.url:'http://myurl.com'}")
```

Comment: For me on Spring 4.2 that resulted in: `'http://myurl.com'` (single quotes part of the value). Simply removing the single quotes fixed it. If I would guess, it splits on the first colon and the first part is the variable; the remainder is the value.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to pass a list of Strings that contain colon with default value then do like:

```
@Value("${parameterName:}#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList(\"abc:1\",\"def:2\")}")

private List<String> parameters;
```

Answer (score 0):

On Spring version 3.2 the default value works without quotes.