# how to use environment variable with spring boot when the value having special symbol like ':'?

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables

I'm trying to use environment variable in a application.properties in the Spring Boot, but the static value has some ':' in the middle.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = {$URI:mongodb://user:pass@host.mlab.com:port/db}
```

But this don't work, i guess it's because

> mongodb://user:pass@host.mlab.com:port/db

has ':' in it.
I want to use environment variable when available, but if don't use the static configuration, like this works pretty well:

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

Do anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31711308/2970947

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent the string double quotes

```
{$URI: "mongodb://user:pass@host.mlab.com:port/db"}
```

Comment: it does not work for me. Spring Boot: 2.7.3