# Spring boot default resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resources

I am getting resource with the following manner.

```
@Value("classpath:user-pass.json")
private Resource resource;
```

I want to set a default value for the resource if the above resource not found. We can set default value in property extraction as follow

```
@Value("${some.key:my default value}")
private String string;
```

I need help in applying a similar formula to resource acquiration.

Resource above is from

```
package org.springframework.core.io
```

Comment: Can you please add the `Resource` class definition? Or is it https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html?

Comment: @JoãoDias yes that one

Comment: The same will work for a `Resource`. The type doesn't matter.

Comment: @M.Deinum but could not find the syntax for that. can you clarify? There is already colon.

Comment: There is no difference. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31711412/2696260 just do `${some.key:classpath:user-pass.json}` (assuming you are on Spring 4.2 or up) and it should just work.

Comment: ${classpath:model.json:classpath:default.json} does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. I would say that your best option would be to load the `Resource` yourself if it is `null` after Bean creation:

```java
@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() {
    if (resource == null) {
        resource = new ClassPathResource("default.json");
    }
}
```